# what is wrong with this reasoning???

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

we have the next function:
$$z=f(x,y)$$
take the differential
$$dz=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}dx+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}dy$$
divided for $dz$:$$1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dz}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dz}$$
we have for the chain rule, $\frac{\partial f}{\partial w}\frac{dw}{dz}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}$, using this fact:
$$1=\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=2\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}\qquad\rightarrow\qquad \frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=\frac{1}{2}$$
solve this equation, gives the next result:
$$f=\frac{z}{2}+C$$
rewrite this:
$$z=2f+C$$
wich is obvuisly wrong, because $f$ don't depend of $z$.Therefore $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z}=0$.
$$$$Other fact is $z=f$ not $z=2f$

God bless us

Comment: how idd you get df/dz = 1/2, which directional derivative..?

Comment: @SakethMalyala  what mean idd?

Comment: If $f$ depends on only $w$, and $w$ depends on only $x$, then the chain rule rule $\frac{df}{dw} \frac{dw}{dx} = \frac{df}{dx}$ holds. In this case, $f$ depends on $x$ and $y$, so $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \neq \frac{df}{dx}$.

Comment: @Harry thanks a lot

Comment: You are welcome. Would you like me to post it as an answer so you can accept it?

Comment: @Harry Ok post the answer, i vote up

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. Some food for thought:

1. What are $\frac{dx}{dz}$ and $\frac{dy}{dz}$? And don't just say 'the derivative of x with respect to z'. Think about the problem at hand. What do these quantities mean?
2. The chain rule you mention is no chain rule I've ever heard of. It bears a resemblance to a chain rule but usually when there's partial derivatives involved there is more than one term.
3. You say 'f doesn't depend on z' but what are you basing that on? What is $f$ here? We often confuse variable names and functional relationships. For instance, your first line is $f(x,y) = z$. Consider that you could have written $z = z(x,y)...$ how would you frame this question if you chose that notation?
4. (Really a hint for 1) Note that when you have $z=f(x,y)$, you are reducing the system from two variables to one, so this isn't invertible, many values of $x$ correspond to each $z$. So $x$ isn't really a proper function of $z.$

Comment: @spaceisdarkgrren thanks, sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: the last question, is this true?$$\frac{dz}{dz}=\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}\frac{dx}{dz}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}\frac{dy}{dz}$$ thanks in advance. God bless you.

Comment: No need to be sorry, it was a good question and making mistakes informally reasoning about differentials is really common. As to your follow up question, read items 1,4 above.